# Conjecture That The Only Nearly Perfect Numbers Are The Powers Of 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers, perfect-powers

Call a natural number $n$ “flawed” if its aliquot sum (the sum of its factors less than itself) is $n-1$. Show that the set of flawed numbers is equivalent to the set of perfect powers of $2$.

Experimentally speaking, I wrote a little Python program that verified my conjecture up to $2^{15}$, but I am aware that that is by no means the same thing as a proof.

Comment: Can you prove that every power of two is a flawed number? (I can; my question is whether *you* know how to do so.)

Comment: Yes. The sum of the powers of $2$ less than $2^n$ is $2^n-1$. What I don’t know how to do is prove the converse.

Comment: The _deficiency_ of $n$ is defined (see [A033879](https://oeis.org/A033879)) as $2n$ minus the sum of divisors of $n$. Since $n$ is always its own divisor, the defiency is therefore $n$ minus the aliquot sum. So your conjecture is equivalent to: Only powers of 2 have deficiency 1. This property appears as a comment (without argument) on the referenced OEIS page; the citations therein may have a proof.

Comment: As an addendum to the above, the Wiki page on the [aliquot sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sum) remarks: "The quasiperfect numbers (if such numbers exist) are the numbers n whose aliquot sums equal $n + 1$. The almost perfect numbers (which include the powers of 2, being the only known such numbers so far) are the numbers n whose aliquot sums equal $n − 1$." The latter remark would appear to confirm that this is a known conjecture. More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPerfectNumber.html.

Comment: Oh no! From Wikipedia, “the only known even almost perfect numbers are those of the form 2k for some positive number k; however, it has not been shown that all almost perfect numbers are of this form.” My question is an open problem in math!

Comment: That is simultaneously entertaining and deflating. Entertaining because it means that I came up with an unsolved conjecture independently, and deflating because it means I will get no answer (expediently, at least).

Comment: any odd $n$ would need an even number of odd proper divisors. Forces it to be a square.

Comment: another observation two disjoint numbers that work have divisor sum product that wont.

Comment: Related:  The number $n$ is almost perfect if and only if
$$\frac{2n}{n + 1} \leq I(n) < \frac{2n + 1}{n + 1}$$
where $I(n)=\sigma(n)/n$ is the abundancy index of $n$ and $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$.

Comment: I recently asked upto which limit is has been checked whether $\sigma(n)=2n-1$ (which is equivalent to what you are looking for) only holds for the powers of $2$. Some user claimed that such a number not being a power of $2$ must exceed $10^{22}$

Comment: An even larger bound do we have for the analogue equation $\sigma(n)=2n+1$. No solution is known , and if one exists, it must exceed $10^{35}$